# Form fill by viewing document on same UI

Tags: usability, forms, gui-design, user-expectation

What could be the best UI desing if we need to provide a user a single UI where user can view the document uploaded at the backend and fill the form by viewing the details available in the documents.

Also, how to highlight if some fields are already verified, failed or on hold status at every field level and provide the summary view.

component:

- Survey Form
- Document view
- field level status
- list of pending actions

Basic Wireframe:

[image]

Comment: There is too much going in this question. Can you separate the document question from the highlight question? Also there is much more detail needed in order to get a reasonable answer. What ideas, sketches, wireframes do you already have, can you add them to the question? It's better to ask a question in form of a problem that needs to be solved instead of hoping for answers that will define a possible problem and solution for you.

Comment: @jazZRo: Uploaded the basic wireframe.

Answer (score 1):

we can try this.
Initially Layout will be same as yours.

[image]

When user clicks on view document, related document will slide in from right edge. Side navbar will slide out to generate more space for document. when user click on close document, document will slide out and side navbar will slide in.

[image]

Refer this for more [page-slide-stay-on-the-page-pattern](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/page-slide-stay-on-the-page-pattern)